# Generate a live stream url from the electron desktopCapturer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stream, electron

I'm using the [desktopCapturer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer) api from electron to display a live stream of my computer (and having the choice of the desktops to display via the `getSources()` method).

```
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source.name === 'Electron') {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
              minWidth: 1280,
              maxWidth: 1280,
              minHeight: 720,
              maxHeight: 720
            }
          }
        })
        handleStream(stream)
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
      }
      return
    }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
  const video = document.querySelector('video')
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => video.play()
}

function handleError (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

I'm trying to make the stream available on a react-native app, but I'm facing a problem:

- The [react-native-webrt](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/issues/339) library does not support the actual webRTC version (`ontrack` does not exists)
- [react-native-live-stream](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-live-stream) is only working with a stream url

Can I make the `desktopCapturer` stream available through an URL? Do you have a better way to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have done with this issue then could you please share it here, i am also facing the same issue